# Finding equivalent of $p\land q$ using only implication and $\bot$

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

What is a formula equivalent of $p\land q$ that uses only $p$ and $q$, $\to$ and $\bot$ connectives?

$\to$ is so confusing... Could anyone help me out? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's confusing, just look at the truth table of p->q

Comment: Why the confusion about $\to$? Many beginners seem to confuse "implies" with "causes." When we write $Rain \to Cloudy$, we do NOT mean that rain CAUSES cloudiness. We mean only that, at the moment, it is not both (a) raining and (b) not cloudy. $P\to Q \space\space \equiv \space \space \neg (P\land \neg Q)$.

Answer (score 4):

We have
$$p\to q\equiv\neg p\lor q$$
By De Morgan's laws
$$p\land q\equiv\neg(\neg p\lor\neg q)$$
We can express $\neg p$ as $p\to\bot$, so
$$p\land q\equiv(p\to(q\to\bot))\to\bot$$

Comment: Yes. $p\wedge q$ is true exactly when it is *false that $p$ and $q$ entail falsehood*.